# Accidentally i have uninstalled my home launcher

Tags: security, email, facebook

there is no launcher in my phone.i also switched off and switched on . it showed only samsung nothing else.My device was already rooted and i thought by factory data reset it would work but now i can't  even open the recovery mode.i guess my phone is empty. please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first:

1. You have to Factory reset your phone and then reboot it, most probably it will get switched on. Then you create or login with Google ID (you can as I did it in my old Micromax A76).
2. Now tap on setting===>app===>Google Play===>launch. (If you have logged in, you can easily launch Google store by only this method if "Home Launcher" is uninstalled in any rooted Android device.
3. Now install any 3rd party launcher from Goggle like Go Launcher, Solo Launcher or any launcher.

Enjoy :) You have got your phone back from a Coma ;)

P.S.  *emphasized text* Please make sure you are not doing Factory reset again without putting the apk of your current launcher in root folder.

Feel free to ask anything regarding this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try method of Shri Bhagwan described or you can always use ADB to push an app into your phone.
When phone boots up, complete the welcome procedure(Name, Google account adding etc.) then open status bar and go to settings and turn on USB Debugging.
Then open terminal(Linux) or cmd(windows) and write adb install (appname).apk
Make sure you have adb binaries to execute command and required drivers to recognize your phone.
Hope it helps. :)